# Newly created table in onUpgrade() doesn't include NOT NULL column settings

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I upgrade my app's database from one version to another, I execute the following commands:

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tags_vocab RENAME TO tmp_tags_vocab");
db.execSQL("DROP INDEX idx_tags_vocab");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tags_vocab (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, word_fk INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE)");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tags_vocab (word_fk, tag_id) SELECT word_fk, tag_id from tmp_tags_vocab");
db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_tags_vocab ON tags_vocab (tag_id ASC, word_fk ASC)");
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE tmp_tags_vocab");
```

I need to add the `NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE` parameters to two of **tags_vocab**'s columns, but since sqlite's `ALTER TABLE` doesn't allow that degree of control I have to recreate the whole table.

The problem is that the above commands all appear to run and get committed just fine, but when I pull the post-upgrade database from the app's private database directory, the "modified" table appears to be completely unchanged. This is the DDL of the "modified" table:

```
CREATE TABLE tags_vocab ( 
id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
word_fk    INTEGER,
tag_id     INTEGER 
);
```

The DDL *should* look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tags_vocab ( 
    id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    word_fk    INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE,
    tag_id     INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE 
);
```

Am I doing something wrong when I recreate the table?

Comment: I figured it out, I was forgetting to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` when I finished modifying the database. Adding that in fixed the issue.